# How to update photo and data?

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I've just noticed that even if a photo exists and I update only data, the photo automatically gets deleted. Specifically, please I want a code that can be used to update either data or photo and, or both.

```
qry = "update StudentDetails.Students set StudentName=@StudentName,Day=@Day,Month=@Month,Year=@Year,Age=@Age,DateAdmit=@DateAdmit,Gender=@Gender,GuardianName=@GuardianName,Phone=@Phone,Email=@Email,Address=@Address,City=@City,Region=@Region,Photo = CASE WHEN @Photo IS NULL THEN Photo ELSE @Photo END where StudentId='" & txtStudentID.Text & "'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StudentID", Val(txtStudentID.Text)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StudentName", txtName.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Day", cboDay.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Month", cboMonth.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Year", txtYear.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Age", Val(lblAge.Text)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DateAdmit", DateTimePicker1.Value)).ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Gender", Gender))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@GuardianName", txtGName.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Phone", txtPhone.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Address", txtAddress.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@City", txtTown.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Region", cboRegion.Text))
            If img Is Nothing Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Photo", DBNull.Value))
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Photo", img))
            End If

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Record successfully Updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Informaation)
```

Comment: Can you trace your query using the profiler and post it? When photo becomes null (no deleted) how is the "@Photo" parameter value? What is "Photo" data type?

Comment: A few minor things:  You should use the @StudentID parameter instead of using string concatenation.  Be careful with the Val function.  It may do things you are not expecting when someone puts in an unexpected value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: What datatype is the img variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution. Replace:

```
qry = "update StudentDetails.Students set StudentName=@StudentName,Day=@Day,Month=@Month,Year=@Year,Age=@Age,DateAdmit=@DateAdmit,Gender=@Gender,GuardianName=@GuardianName,Phone=@Phone,Email=@Email,Address=@Address,City=@City,Region=@Region,Photo = CASE WHEN @Photo IS NULL THEN Photo ELSE @Photo END where StudentId='" & txtStudentID.Text & "'"
```

with:

```
    Dim sbQry As New StringBuilder(1000)

    sbQry.Append("update StudentDetails.Students set StudentID=@StudentID,StudentName=@StudentName,Day=@Day,Month=@Month,Year=@Year,Age=@Age,DateAdmit=@DateAdmit,Gender=@Gender,GuardianName=@GuardianName,Phone=@Phone,Email=@Email,Address=@Address,City=@City,Region=@Region")
    If img IsNot Nothing Then
        sbQry.Append(",Photo=@Photo")
    End If
    sbQry.Append(" where StudentId='").Append(txtStudentID.Text).Append("'")

    cmd = New SqlCommand(sbQry.ToString, cn)
```

and replace this:

```
If img Is Nothing Then
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Photo", DBNull.Value))
Else
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Photo", img))
End If
```

with this:

```
If img IsNot Nothing Then
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Photo", img))
End If
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that StringBuilder is not defined, and I've tried defining it but I keep getting that error. Please show me how to define it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hahahaa :) I've now got it. I just replaced StringBuilder(1000)" with System.Text.StringBuilder(1000). I'm glad competent_tech is being of so much help to me.

Comment: @Akaglo: Glad to help. Just remember that when an answer helps you solve your problem, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the answer in order to let future visitors know that this answer helped you solve your question.